# can't fetch image from internet

Tags: android, json, panoramas

I am trying to use [panoramagl-android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/) library to display panoramic images. My scenario requires panorama to be loaded from the internet and can't be saved in local res folder of android, as I will be having hundreds of images.

I have been able to successfully load panorama jpegs from res folder but failed to do the same for files located on the internet.

I am trying load panorama images using JSON as I have already mentioned that I will be having hundreds of images and setting their hotspots via code is simply not possible.

Here is my activity loading JSON from res folder:

```
/**
 * This event is fired when root content view is created
 * @param contentView current root content view
 * @return root content view that Activity will use
 */
@Override
protected View onContentViewCreated(View contentView)
{
    //Load layout
    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    //Add 360 view
    mainView.addView(contentView, 0);

    loadSpherical2FromJson();

    //Return root content view
    return super.onContentViewCreated(mainView);
}

private void loadSpherical2FromJson() {
    try
    {
        PLILoader loader;
        loader = new PLJSONLoader("res://raw/json_spherical2");
        this.load(loader, true, new PLTransitionBlend(2.0f));
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And my JSON is this:

```
{
  // "urlBase": "res://",
  "urlBase": "http://",
  "type": "spherical2",
  "keep": "all",
  "images":
  {
    // "preview": "raw/casabella_hall_preview",
    // "image": "raw/casabella_hall_2048"
    "preview": "statichost.herokuapp.com/panoramagl/casabella_hall_preview.jpg",
    "image": "statichost.herokuapp.com/panoramagl/casabella_hall_2048.jpg"
  },
  "camera":
  {
    "keep": "all|~atvRange|~rotation|~fov",
    "atvMin": -90.0,
    "atvMax": 90.0,
    "vLookAt": 0.0,
    "hLookAt": 170.0
  },
  "hotspots":
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "atv": 0.0,
      "ath": 170.0,
      "width": 0.05,
      "height": 0.05,
      // "image": "raw/hotspot",
      "image": "statichost.herokuapp.com/panoramagl/hotspot.png",
      "alpha": 0.8,
      "overAlpha": 1.0,
      "onClick": "lookAt(0.0, 90.0, true);"
    }
  ]
}
```

The commented out code for res:// is working but the http:// is not working. I will also need this JSON data to be fetched from internet (but one thing at a time).

Here is a github repo for the whole app: https://github.com/ishanatmuz/PanoramaGL-Test/tree/Spherical2Json

Please Help.

UPDATE:

Earlier I was getting `Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class ....` as info but not as error in LogCat so I didn't suspected that it could be the problem. Anyhoo I added commons-httpclient-3.1.jar in libs folder, to eliminate it, assuming that could be the problem. However, now when I am running the application, I see a circular loader animation indicating something is loading, but then I am still seeing the black screen. In the network monitor, I still can't see any network requests getting fired.

I have updated the code in the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem. I was putting the INTERNET permission in the manifest at the wrong location. It is working now.

The working version of the code is updated in the GitHub repo.
However, I am linking the code versions for anyone else having similar problems with PanoramaGl integration in Android.

1. PanoramaGL integration using jar files [source code](https://github.com/ishanatmuz/PanoramaGL-Test/tree/5ab95a66a4393609695b647ea38b0726876a1402)
2. PanoramaGL integration using source of library [source code](https://github.com/ishanatmuz/PanoramaGL-Test/tree/2c2af20b55a0de2bfa6b8ff8accff8f38b8ab742)

I would like to mention that I had to move some library files and some lib glues files to remove duplication of files and thus reducing APK size.

In my moving around of files. I found out that using the jar files (Method 1 mentioned above) as library gives me an APK of 2.8 M.B. and using the source code (Method 2 mentioned above) gives me an APK of 2.6 M.B.

Another thing that the user might consider is method count, as Android has an [upper limit on method count of 65536](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement panorama using the code provided by you in the above answer. I am getting a black screen when I tried implementing cubic type via local json file, image size 1024x1024. Any idea why do I see a black screen?

Comment: I can only try to help if you provide me with the code and all the files.

Comment: Hey thanks for offering help. While I was debugging, somehow managed to make it work.. :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can contact me anytime if you need some help.